# Why do virtual inheritance and virtual destructor cause COM factory to generate exception?

Tags: com, virtual-inheritance, virtual-destructor

This is going to be a bit complicated, but I have been working on it for two days with no progress, so I could *really* use some SO help.

I'm trying to write a COM server, something I've done successfully several times. In order to move the implementation of an interface that all COM objects must implement (specifically, `IUnknown`) into a superclass (which I am calling `Base`), I need that superclass to inherit virtually from `IUnknown`. That's because the COM object will inherit from the superclass and also from the public interface for the object, which must also inherit from `IUnknown`.

Once again, I have a "diamond" inheritance structure:

```
                       IUnknown
                      /        \
                     /          \
Base::virtual IUnknown          IComObject::virtual IUnknown
                     \          /
                      \        /
             CComObject::Base, IComObject
```

Part of implementing a COM server is the creation of a "factory" object, which is, itself, a COM object and, therefore, must implement `IUnknown`. Alas, the factory object must also implement `IClassFactory`, which inherits from `IUnknown`, but not virtually. Therefore, the factory object must also implement `IUnknown`, even if it inherits from my new superclass, `Base`.

Now, one of the things `IUnknown`'s implementation must do is provide a "suicide" method that, at the appropriate time, will delete the COM object. In order to succeed in doing this, `Base`'s destructor must be virtual. So, to start, `Base`'s declaration looks like this:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

class Base : public virtual IUnknown
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {};
};
```

None of the `IUnknown` methods are declared here, though they will be at some future time, when I solve the bug I'm working on now. Right now, the only class that will inherit from Base is my factory class, called `CFactory5`, which must (for the reasons outlined above) implement `IUnknown` itself.

Here's the declaration and complete implementation (as stubs) of `CFactory5`:

```cpp
class CFactory5 : public Base, public IClassFactory
{
public:
    STDMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppv) override { return E_FAIL; };
    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef(void) override { return E_FAIL; };
    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release(void) override { return E_FAIL; };

    STDMETHODIMP CreateInstance(IUnknown *pUnk, REFIID riid, void** ppv) { return E_FAIL; };
    STDMETHODIMP LockServer(BOOL fLock) { return E_FAIL; };
};
```

Now, all COM servers must, by contract, implement and export two functions, `DllGetClassObject`, which provides a pointer to the factory object, and `DllCanUnloadNow`, which lets COM know if the entire server library can be unloaded.  Here, along with the class id, are those two functions, stubbed down to the bare minimum that could at least return a pointer to a `CFactory5` object:

```cpp
#include <initguid.h>

DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_ICounter,
    0x8b63c61, 0x467a, 0x46c7, 0x9e, 0xf5, 0x99, 0xe, 0x8, 0x54, 0x5b, 0xc2);

STDAPI DllGetClassObject(REFCLSID rclsid, REFIID riid, void** ppv)
{
    if (rclsid != CLSID_ICounter)
        return CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE;

    *ppv = new CFactory5;

    return S_OK;
}

STDAPI DllCanUnloadNow()
{
    return S_FALSE;
}
```

With all those stubs, this factory object isn't going to work very well, but the problems that would cause never get a chance to show themselves, because *none* of the factory object's methods ever get called (according to the debugger). Instead, after `DllGetClassObject` returns, and before anything else I can catch with the debugger is called, I get this error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in Client5.exe: 0xC0000005:
Access violation executing location 0x00000000.
```

Here is the code for `Client5.exe`:

```cpp
int main()
{
    HRESULT hrtop = CoInitialize(NULL);

    if (FAILED(hrtop))
    {
        printf("CoInitialize failed: 0x%08x\n", hrtop);
        exit(hrtop);
    }

    void* pCF = NULL;

    CoGetClassObject(CLSID_ICounter, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, NULL,   IID_IClassFactory, &pCF);

    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

When `CoGetClassObject` is called, that leads to a call to `DllGetClassObject`, which I am able to catch in the debugger. Stepping along, I can see that a new `CFactory5` object is created and a pointer to it is stored in `*ppv`. Nothing goes wrong until I "continue" past the end of `DllGetClassObject`. With no other code of mine ever being called, I get the exception described above.

Now, one of my stub methods for `CFactory5` *does* get called if I either remove the `virtual` keyword from `Base`'s declaration of `IUnknown` as its base class, *or* if I remove the `virtual` keyword from the declaration of `Base`'s destructor. Whatever is blowing up before that call to my stub method is made, stops blowing up if I do either of those things. But I need those things both to be virtual, for the reasons outline above.

So, at this point, I am stumped. I can't trim out any more code without sacrificing an essential design element, and I can't seem to get what I have running to show me an error I can examine with the debugger. I gather that there is something I still don't understand about virtual inheritance and/or virtual destructors (though I'm doubly stumped as to why the destructor would matter, since it is never called).

If anyone can explain this to me, I'd be supremely grateful. Even if no one can do that, if anyone can suggest more ways to try to debug it, I'd be extremely grateful.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community (Update 3) and Windows 10.

Any ideas?

Comment: COM is very particular about the specific binary layout of its interfaces. Virtual inheritance causes the compiler to generate binary layout incompatible with COM. In your example, `IComObject` is not a COM interface. I suggest you look at [ATL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ax346b7.aspx) - what you are trying to achieve is a solved problem.

Comment: `*ppv = new CFactory5;` Make it `*ppv = static_cast<IClassFactory*>(new CFactory5);`. Your current code effectively does `reinterpret_cast` instead, which is not at all the same thing. You are not, in fact, giving the caller `IClassFactory*` pointer. This has nothing to do with your virtual inheritance games, it's a more basic mistake.

Comment: Thanks, @Igor , you are absolutely correct. I am a long-time C programmer, so I keep making assumptions that don't apply to C++. I believe this reflects a couple of them. Please post your comment as an answer and I'll check it as best. Much appreciated!